# safe to edit CRConfig.xml in Crystal Reports Developer full edition on production machine?

Tags: memory, crystal-reports, jvm

Here's a question from a Crystal n00b.

Accessing a database using JDBC and using the Crystal 2008 SP1 user interface (File/Export etc) I was having problems running out of Java heap.

I finally started digging around in the software install folders and stumbled across CRConfig.xml.  It has lots of parameters like JVMMaxHeap, documented here.

http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/en/JRC_SDK/jrc_java_dg_doc/doc/jrcsdk_java_dg/CRDBJavaServer_Ref2.html

Jacking up JVMMaxHeap solved my problem.

My question is this: is it safe just to edit this file on a production system?  Or is there some user interface that I haven't discovered yet that sets this in a more formal way.  I am really hoping to build a foolproof system that can crank out reports 24x7.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it is indeed OK to edit this file, by paying too much money to SAP tech support.

But, I also found out that only a sucker (yours truly) will try to use Crystal (2008) JDBC data access; this scheme fires up a JVM, loads the whole data set into it, then passes it along to the report engine. That's fine as long as the data set is small enough to fit in the JVM.

Real data sets aren't.